# Has is_archived() for sites in a multisite changed with WP 4.7?

Tags: functions, multisite, updates, conditional-tags

I have a piece of code displaying a list of sites in my multisite, and I want to exclude the archived ones:

```
$mySites = ( wp_get_sites( $args ) );

foreach ( $mySites as $blog ) {

    if ( ! ( is_archived($blog) ) ) {
         switch_to_blog( $blog['blog_id'] );
         printf( '%s<a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\r\n", $TagLi, home_url(), get_option( 'blogname' ) );  

    restore_current_blog();
    }
}
```

Before updating to 4.7, this was working correctly. Now, it doesn't exclude archived sites anymore, it prints out a complete list.

Has the function `is_archived()` changed? Or what can the problem be?

Comment: > wp_get_sites function has been deprecated. Use get_sites() instead. visit this link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_sites/

Comment: @KanonChowdhury That doesn't answer the question. The code above should work nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you @toscho, next time i will concern about such issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try out the following code somewhere and post the output?

```
$mySites = wp_get_sites($args);
foreach ($mySites as $blog){
    print_r(get_blog_status($blog['blog_id'], 'archived'));
}
```

If this works, I suspect the code behind `is_archived()` used to understand blog-objects, but the [function is supposed to recieve only the blog ID](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_archived/), not the whole object.

Your code should be the following:

```
$mySites = wp_get_sites($args);
foreach ($mySites as $blog){
    if (!is_archived($blog['blog_id'])){
        switch_to_blog( $blog['blog_id'] );
        printf( '%s<a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\r\n", $TagLi, home_url(), get_option( 'blogname' ) );  

        restore_current_blog();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. It posts 0 when the site is not archived, and 1 where it is, correctly.

Comment: See my updated answer! :)

Answer (score 3):

Note that `get_sites()` has a different output than the deprecated  `wp_get_sites()` function in WordPress 4.7+.

The `get_sites()` function returns an array of `WP_Site` objects, but `wp_get_sites()` returns an array of arrays.

So if you use `get_sites()`, you need to adjust your code snippet with:

```
is_archived( $blog->blog_id )
```

and

```
switch_to_blog( $blog->blog_id );
```

instead of using `$blog['blog_id']`.